# Не срабатывает функция с bind()

Tags: javascript, html, функции

Почему в данном примере функция `handleClick` не запускается?
При этом, если убрать `bind` и оставить только `handleClick()`, то все работает, но теряется контекст.

```html
 <div id='container'>
  <ul>
    <li id='home' onclick='handleClick.bind(this)'>Home</li>
    <li id='services' onclick='handleClick.bind(this)'>Services</li>
    <li id='about' onclick='handleClick.bind(this)'>About</li>
    <li id='contact' onclick='handleClick.bind(this)'>Contact us</li>
  </ul>
  <div id='selected'>Selected: Home</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function handleClick() {
    selected.innerHTML = 'Selected: '+ this.innerHTML;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: абсолютно бессмысленная идея использовать bind таким образом

Comment: почему бессмысленная?

Comment: Ну так вы сделали забинденную функцию, но не вызвали её. Вообще я бы вам посоветовал передать this как аргумент, а не костылять с контекстами

Comment: [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) почитайте на всякий случай

Comment: вы знаете, как сделать так, чтобы  забинденная функция в данном случае вызывалась?

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, у меня в соседней вкладке открыто. Я, может быть, не вижу чего-то важного)

Comment: @Kasparova оно создает функцию, сделайте `handleClick.bind(this)()` так и она вызовется, но все же лучше передайте this как аргумент и все будет ок

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych благодарствую!)

Comment: [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) еще это прочтите, мб вам больше подойдет

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych вы правы. Спасибо!